# Is Apache Tomcat IPv6 compatible without any server.xml changes?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

We've been having some spurious issues that may be attributed to some network changes due to IPv6 compatibility.

I tried the workaround: address="0.0.0.0" in the Connector tag, but the access log still contains only IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is accepting connections from IPv6 clients, then you will get IPv6 addresses sometimes. Are you fronting Tomcat with another web server that may be accepting IPv6 connections and forwarding them over IPv4? If so, you'll need to reconfigure the web server.

You could try adding `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to your `CATALINA_OPTS` on the application server.

**UPDATE 2015-09-03**

There are other reasons why you might be getting IPv6 addresses in your access log, even if you have IPv6 *completely disabled* on the server. For example, if you have a reverse proxy in front of Tomcat, it could be sending an `X-Forwarded-For` header which includes an IPv6 address in it. Assuming you have Tomcat "properly" configured, Tomcat will log the *real* client's IP address (in IPv6 form) to your access log, instead of using the reverse proxy's IP address to your log (which would be useless, since it would appear that all requests came from the reverse proxy).

So if your software can't handle IPv6 for some reason, you really need to get that software fixed because you really can't hide from IPv6.